# Perception of Phi Beta Kappa on a resume?

Tags: united-states, cv, undergraduate, honor-societies, liberal-arts

I'm a student in the US, about to graduate with a BS in zoology. I've just been invited to join [Phi Beta Kappa](https://www.pbk.org/) and am trying to find some more up-to-date discussions of whether or not it's worth it and I see a lot of conflicting opinions/information.

It costs $99 for me to join, which some have said reflects poorly on the society, while others say PBK is super prestigious and eye-catching. I've seen some saying it has gotten them positions, and others say its meaningless or they even look down on people who include it on their resumes.

I'll most likely go to grad school eventually and have no intentions currently to do any work/study outside of the US (I've seen many folks from outside the US saying they see honor societies and have a negative reaction because of Greek Life). Anyone have thoughts on this?

Comment: I would hope people responsible for graduate admissions do not take into account in which organisations you are in (but I am from Europe abd don't know this organisation).

Comment: Do you have any more obligations other than to pay this fee?

Comment: My mother, now in her 80's, has considered it useful to maintain her PBK membership for more than 60 years now.

Comment: Note: This is related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18193/do-graduate-schools-pay-attention-to-joining-phi-kappa-phi-or-other-honor-societ

Comment: And this: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10173/does-membership-of-academic-honour-societies-carry-any-professional-weight-rec

Comment: Is the $99 fee one-time or per-year? I found an [old answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/10174/958) on this site which states that PBK "does not require paying a fee to be inducted", so at the moment I have contradicting information about these costs.

Answer (score 9):

I am looking at this from a European perspective.
Also I focus on the perception and not whether this is accurate, which does not matter that much – whether you like it or not.
You can neither expect readers to research this detail of your CV to fully understand it nor to suppress subconscious bias by the impression they get from items they do not fully understand.

As confirmed by some of the comments by other European members here, the vast majority of information of US Greek-letter societies that trickle over to Europe is about drug abuse, sexual misconduct, dehumanising initiation rituals, and nepotism. Therefore mentioning a membership in such an organisation (without any further explanation) risks leaving a bad impression. At the very least I would try to mitigate the risk by explicitly denoting it as an honour society – which can only have so much effect since that’s not a protected term.

Also, while a little Internet research suffices to debunk the worst associations, it does not leave the best impression:

- It’s surprisingly difficult to find a recent independent characterisation on this society. You mainly find self-representation and Wikipedia (which is currently dominated by self-representation). The best you can find with reasonable effort are [two](https://www.nytimes.com/1996/05/26/nyregion/phi-beta-kappa-key-being-turned-down-by-many-honorees.html) [articles](https://www.post-gazette.com/news/education/2005/11/04/Phi-beta-what-Students-saying-no-to-elite-honor-society/stories/200511040225) from 1996 and 2005, respectively, about declining membership and recognition, in which the society leaves a rather entitled impression. Also, this very question and others on this site are already amongst the first things you find. This somewhat suggests that the society has since evaporated into meaninglessness.
- The society’s main activity appears to be selecting and recruiting new members and documenting their achievements, which strikes me as awkwardly circular. There a few awards, scholarships, and fellowships, but these seem secondary.
- The primary selection criterion seems to be grades, scholarly achievements, and learning another language, which should be featured on your CV anyway. It seems like a society that charges mountains to put a golden badge on them stating their height (analogy stolen from [Leonard Cohen](https://www.theguardian.com/music/2016/oct/14/leonard-cohen-giving-nobel-to-bob-dylan-like-pinning-medal-on-everest)). Thus, listing membership appears to be somewhat redundant.

Mind that this is just an impression (after all the difficulty of finding information from reliable sources is one of the things that form this impression), but at the very least it suggests a considerable marketing failure.

Comment: Actually, the faculty in PBK are likely to sponsor a series of lectures on campus of distinguished intellectuals and academics and give students an opportunity to meet them.

Comment: And, do you look for ways to give your own best students a boost? Would it be worthwhile to have some formal way to do that?

Comment: @Buffy: *Actually, the faculty in PBK are likely to sponsor a series of lectures on campus of distinguished intellectuals and academics and give students an opportunity to meet them.* – If you need to point that out, that’s a part of the problem I am describing. (Also, I don’t see why you would need an honour society for this.) — *And, do you look for ways to give your own best students a boost? Would it be worthwhile to have some formal way to do that?* – I really do not want to debate the honour societies in general here. I am not saying they are bad; I am saying they leave a bad impression.

Answer (score 3):

Include it. [Phi Beta Kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_Beta_Kappa) isn't a part of the [Animal House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_House) culture. It is an honor, bestowed by the faculty and only those respected by the faculty are considered.

If someone confuses it with the [Dekes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_Kappa_Epsilon) it is their ignorance. The faculty who will review your applications know what it means, maybe even in Europe though comments here make me wonder. So, if you want to apply in Europe, explain that it is an honor society.

For those offended by this answer, note that PBK is **not** a fraternity. It has no initiation rites. It is purely and simply an invitation only honor society.

---

Disclaimer, neither a Deke, nor a PBK. No disrespect intended for either institution.

---

Caveat: Perhaps, for applications to any European institution you will need to make the nature of PBK blindingly obvious if you include it. The impression here, from comments and other answers, is that too many Europeans may make too many incorrect assumptions about Greek letter societies, assuming that all are only for drunks and such. And you may not get a chance to follow up. Sad.

Comment: "Even in Europe". Mm... not sure 'about that. I don't want to be disrespectful for such an institution, but I have no idea what it means, and I'm pretty sure that most of my European colleagues don't know it either. And, yes, like it or not, many people around this part of the world associate _any_ fraternity to Animal House.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano but I'm pretty sure you could google it if you saw it. Yes? It isn't a fraternity. It is an honor society. Look and learn.

Comment: I doubt that any "chapter" has a a chapter house and I'm certain that they never hold keggers. Afternoon tea, perhaps, but not keggers.

Comment: Do you really want a selection committee to Google a fraternity name? ;-)

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano, does everything Greek offend you? It isn't  fraternity.

Comment: Another European here who does not know PBK. The practical matter is that if I am looking at that CV, it will be one of many. I am not going google everything I see there. I probably won't hold it against her or him, but I will probably just skip it unless I am really interested in that individual.

Comment: I think it really depends whether or not your participation in that organization brought you any type of character development. On my campus, fraternities like to party but they also put a heavy focus on academics. In fact, if not for joining a fraternity, I would not be in graduate school (joining helped sky rocket my grades). If you are proud of the organization, put it in on.

Comment: another European here: did not know the difference between deke and pkb. i think inclusion into a resume would give me a bad impression

Comment: @Jakob. There are other honor societies, some of them discipline specific: https://upe.acm.org. The use of Greek letters without association with "social clubs" is common enough. You should educate yourself before you act on any "bad impression".

Comment: Who is "the faculty" mentioned in your answer, exactly?

Comment: Imagine a European professor reading a CV mentioning a Greek-letter organisation. The only thing most of them know about these organisations is Animal House or worse. They now have two appropriate options: 1) Educate themselves – which is a considerable effort for a single CV item and often impossible due to time constraints. 2) Try to forget it as good as possible – which is inevitably imperfect: We cannot avoid being biased. — What many of the above commentors are saying is that if they chose Option 2, this is the bias they would have. It’s not that they are intentionally ignorant.

Comment: For what it's worth, the concept of an "honor society" in general seems fairly US-specific (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honor_society). On a practical level, as someone in the UK who's not too familiar with US honor society culture, I'm not sure I'd know what to make of it, so I'd probably just ignore it in practice. Not saying that's a good thing, but that's the reality. I'd be much more interested in looking at your published papers and talking to you about them; what society you're in wouldn't be much of a factor in any decision-making.

Comment: Out of interest, what should one make of someone's membership in a US honor society, if anything? What's the acceptance rate for membership, for instance? (For example, if they only accept one in a million people, you're the one, and you weren't competing with muppets, that might be impressive; if they accept everybody, or only muppets apply, maybe less so.)

Comment: @StuartGolodetz, actually you don't _apply_ for membership. It is an invitation only organization. It is fairly ubiquitous at prestigious US universities and colleges. There are many faculty there who are members and who, themselves, attended other prestigious places (Ivy League, and such). Those faculty invite students to membership. Most students would consider it a high honor to be invited - an indication of academic success generally. So, high performing students at universities that generally expect high performance.

Comment: @Buffy Thanks for the explanation. In that case, though, how is nepotism avoided, in practice? Are there objective minimum criteria that people who are invited have to meet, to limit the ability of faculty members to simply invite their friends (even if they're not so good)? And if so, are there also joining mechanisms for people who meet those criteria but don't have friends on the faculty to invite them? How are these organisations prevented from becoming "old boys' networks"? After all, going to a prestigious place and having prestigious friends are not quite the same thing as being good.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz, typically it is a group of faculty members inviting some students. Social pressures mitigate against inviting the unqualified. I don't know the specific procedures, but assume a faculty member would nominate someone and the nomination would be discussed. It isn't "I" invite "you", it is "we" invite you. It isn't a "friends" group. I've been invited to join some such things, but never had an inkling that I was being considered. One was a general honors society and the other was UPE (the ACM's CS honors society) so field specific. But if a student works closely with a (cont)

Comment: faculty member and does a good job they are likely to get nominated, I suppose. Is that somehow improper? As I noted before PBK has, as members, 17 US presidents, 40 U.S. Supreme Court Justices, and 136 Nobel Laureates. I think most faculty, voting member in, see the inductees as their academic heirs.

Comment: @Buffy Thanks. I guess that social pressure might help prevent people from nominating someone really bad (as in, it would reflect badly). And group nomination might help as a way of guarding against personal patronage. I guess I'm just concerned about how easy it would be for faculty to bias admission in favour of some students and not others, for reasons other than academic merit. Indeed, when you say that people "see the inductees as their academic heirs", that kind of hints at what I mean (i.e. there's a social/political element besides ability - people might favour their proteges).

Comment: Group nomination doesn't entirely guard against that, either, since you can easily end up in a situation in which "I'll scratch your back if you scratch mine", i.e. "I'll help you invite your guy next time if you help me invite my guy now". Now, you might decline that offer if "my guy" is such a muppet that you'd be ashamed to be associated with inviting him. But if he's "above bar" but not great, and you really want your guy to be invited next time, and I'm the swing vote... It's that kind of horse-trading that ideally wouldn't be a thing.

Comment: I'm a European (UK) who has no idea what PBK is, and also has no idea what an "honor society" is. If seeing it I would assume it was a fraternity, which is also something that doesn't exist here, but is something that we're familiar with (for better or worse) from film and TV.

Answer (score 3):

Save your money.  At best it's meaningless and at worse it associates you with all the negative connotations of Greek society and none of the benefits (such as the social life and a network of close friends and contacts you get to know over the many years at school).

I say it's meaningless because **everything that it purports to represent** - a high GPA, the acclaim of faculty, academic achievement - **can be fully represented without it**.  Simply including your transcript or reporting your GPA, including letters of recommendation from faculty, and reporting on publications, research awards, and so on, covers every base.

Therefore, the only remaining piece of information that joining it tells me is that you respond to phishing-like emails to collect a hundred bucks.

And frankly, I've been a faculty member at two American departments, one of which was selective and the other of which was highly selective (in the top ten most selective in the US), and I had no idea you supposedly get access to this through faculty nomination.  There's been a lot of answers focusing on Europeans who wouldn't know that it's supposedly a good thing, but I've been in the US academic system basically my whole life, and I also don't know that.

Comment: "respond to  phishing-like emails" is pretty uninformed and insulting. Invitations are actually likely to be delivered in person by someone you know. A professor or department head, perhaps.

Comment: The ones I saw were emails that looked like phishing.  It's clear you've had a very different experience with this place than many.